# Acessing the $options array in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes

In this route in Laravel:

```
Route::apiResource('/tipo-documento', ResourceController::class, ["teste" => 'testesssss']);
```

I want to access the array data from the controller, in this case the value of "teste"

I found no solutions

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you don't ... that options array is used for processing the routes for creation, it is not used after that point ... You would have to build your own `ResourceRegistrar` that would add to the 'action' array of the route for you to have access to this data ... that options array is not for random data, it is only for specific data the system is checking for

Comment: you can't, but you can add a middleware to merge a data to your request then use it on your routes which then allows you to get that request data from controller